# How to use loop for splitting text

Tags: flutter, loops, for-loop, dart

I have a single string which contains steps of how to do certain thing. Now I am able to get each step but I am using nested splits so it is getting very long so how can I use `loop` on it.

code

```
 Column(
   children: [
               Text(
                    '${asset.lockoutApplicationProcess.split('2.')[0]}',
                               ),
                Text(
                     '2.${asset.lockoutApplicationProcess.split('2.')[1].split('3.')[0]}',
                   ),
               Text(
                     '3.${asset.lockoutApplicationProcess.split('2.')[1].split('3.')[1].split('4.')[0]}',
                      ),
               Text(
                     '4.${asset.lockoutApplicationProcess.split('2.')[1].split('3.')[1].split('4.')[1].split('5.')[0]}',
                       ),
               Text(
                    '5.${asset.lockoutApplicationProcess.split('2.')[1].split('3.')[1].split('4.')[1].split('5.')[1]}',
                                        
                      ),
 ],
 ),
```

the string,

```
"1. Notify affected personnel. 2. Properly shut down machine. 3. Isolate all energy sources. 4. Apply lockout devices, locks, & tags. 5. Verify total de-energization of all sources."
```

so How can I use loop to reduce the code?

Comment: How does the data in `asset.lockoutApplicationProcess` look like exactly? Maybe some combination of `map` and `reduce` with generator function for `Text` Widgets.

Comment: I have added the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
// Collect all the data in an indexed list, skipping the first (empty) element
final splitData = asset.lockoutApplicationProcess.split(RegExp(r"\d\.")).asMap().entries.skip(1);

// Create a Text Widget for each entry, prefixed with the index number 
final textWidgets = splitData.map((entry) => Text("${entry.key}. ${entry.value}"));

// Render the Text widgets in a column
return Column(children: textWidgets.toList());
```

Note that this will only work for single digits (1-9). If the list could potentially grow beyond 9, you should edit the `RegExp` to take this into account. For example, the regex `RegExp(r"\d+\.")` will also catch numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: ok that works like charm thank you for quick solution and mostly the steps won't go beyond 5